# Is my explanation for why $\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty }{ \frac { 1 }{ n^{ n } } } $ converges correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine whether the series converges or diverges.

$$\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ n^{ n } }  } $$

What I did:

1) We are given that $\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ n^2}  }$ converges to $\frac { \pi^2 }{6}$

2) We also know that $\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ n^n}  } <\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ n^2}  } $

So, by the comparison test, we can conclude that:

$\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ n^{ n } }  } $ is convergent

---

I am unsure of step 2) because of what happens to the bound between $n=1$ and $n=2$. Am I correct in my reasoning? Or is there a significant flaw here?

Comment: The bound required in the comparison test need only hold eventually. It does not matter that the bound fails to hold for finitely many terms. What matters is how quickly the terms decay to zero, in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your solution is correct. As long as the boundes $n=1,n=2$, notice that as long as you can estimate for some $N$ (N can be 1,2,3,4) then the comparison still works. Also, notice

$$ \lim \sqrt[n]{ |a_n| } = \frac{1}{n} \to 0 $$

Thus, also the root test gives the result.

Answer (score 2):

I will provide an extreme overkill, just for fun. Since for any $n\geq 1$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^n e^{-nx}\,dx = \frac{(n-1)!}{n^n}\tag{1} $$
it happens that
$$ 0\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^n} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(xe^{-x})^n}{(n-1)!}\,dx =\int_{0}^{+\infty}x e^{-x} e^{x e^{-x}}\,dx\tag{2}$$
and since $xe^{-x}$ is bounded by $e^{-1}$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$, we have
$$ 0\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^n}\leq e^{e^{-1}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}xe^{-x}\,dx = e^{1/e}.\tag{3} $$
By exploiting
$$ e^{x e^{-x}}\leq 1+ e\left(e^{1/e}-1\right) x e^{-x} \tag{4}$$
we have the improved upper bound
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^n}\leq 1+\frac{e}{4}\left(e^{1/e}-1\right).\tag{5}$$